# Global static variable issue in same app domain in c#

Tags: c#, static

I have a scenario which I faced during developing a common dll for my projects.
Suppose, there is four projects in c#.

- ProjA
- ProjB
- ProjC
- ProjD

Current design:

- *ProjA* has a public static variable `xyz`.
- *ProjA* checks some value from some web services using timer and hold them in variable `xyz` for few validations.
- *ProjA* is referenced in *ProjB* and *ProjC* respectively.
- *ProjB* and *ProjC* are some plugin projects which are basically injected with some plugin engine in *ProjD*.

So the main project which is executing is *ProjD*. Now, I am using *ProjA* from *ProjB* and *ProjC* which pass their individual values to method in *ProjA* and then access *ProjA* variable `xyz` which is public static.

Because *ProjD* is the main application to run in App Pool, value set from *ProjB* is accessible from *ProjC* in *ProjA* `xyz` variable. For example if *ProjA* `xyz` variable is true for *ProjB* then in *ProjC* it is also returning true.

Any ideas how to work around this issue?

Comment: Thank you patrick hofman for properly editing my question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, don't use `public static` properties for this, `public` is accessible to everyone.

One option could be to change the `public` property to `internal` and make your main application a friend assembly, which allows access to `internal` members. The best option though is to rethink your design, because I think there should be some flaws. If there is some state related to one of the plugins, it should keep the state in an object that is not global, but properly scoped.

Comment: Yes I know there is some flaw in my design. But I am really sucked up in logic. Can you help me in working around this issue?

Comment: You need to find out why it needs access to that variable in the first place. Can you rewrite that so it interacts differently with the other end?

Comment: Patrick basically I am building a common dll for my projects which holds plugin specific validation values.
You can say kind of licensing. So when I validate something for ProjB and xyz becomes true then it returns true for ProjC also. Any idea how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

I don't Prefer public static for defining variables. since the changes made by any of the accessing class will reflect globally. You should use `public` instead for this which can also be accessible(but need to instantiate the class).

Comment: Yes you are true. But all I need something like this working in the same scenario.